# What is the best way to test Action mailer without worrying about the enviroment-rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

i need to test the action mailer in my ruby on rails project which is already live.i don't want to go in the mess of creating a new mail server like zimbra on localhost or mess with the configurations of the other environments that i have.moreover i cant think of looking in the log files which will be a complete height of patience.is there any other way to check/debug action mailer in localhost.if yes then how and if not then why not?

Comment: I guess you only want to debug in dev mode right?

Comment: not just debug..but also want to see the log tooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several alternatives:

- define an interceptor in development, see [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3)
- use `letter_opener` gem to see the mail instead of actually sending it, [link to gem](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener)